# 1-2 second home power loss: some circuits stay powered - computer doesn't turn off. How is this possible?

Tags: power, ac, surge-protection

We've been having some local power outages which last for about 1-2 seconds and maybe at times are only 500ms.

I've noticed that we have two computers which stay powered and I'm trying to figure out why.

The first computer is a tower with a Gigabyte m/b, AMD chip, etc. which I have plugged into a power strip with a few other items.

I noticed that when the power loss occurred our wifi router and cable modem (on another circuit also plugged into their own surge protector strips) would both get rebooted.  Other things (lamps, etc.) flicker off and back on.

I was guessing that it was because this computer happened to be on a home circuit that had nothing else on it and that was why it stayed powered.
This computer is plugged into a power protector strip but that's it.

Today I remembered my headless MacMini is also plugged into that same power strip (and obviously on the same home circuit) however, the 1-2 second power loss does indeed cause the Mac Mini to turn off.

There's another desktop computer in the house that is on a different circuit that also does not experience power loss during these outages.

Is this related to something about the power supply in my desktop?
Is it related to the home circuit I happen to be on?
Maybe you can't tell with this information, but I'm wondering if this is a common thing or if it just so happens that the two computers' power supplies / surge strip are helping in some way.

Comment: Well think about it like this: You fill a bucket full of water. You suddenly create a hole at the bottom of the bucket. The water won’t suddenly empty all at once, right?

Comment: @KingDuken Very good analogy and I was guessing that might be happening.  But I wasn't sure if _just_ a standard power supply in a computer would work that way and especially for up to 2 seconds or so.  Thanks

Comment: For each device (that fails or not) what are the stated operating voltage limits on the product? I'm thinking that you don't lose power completely but partially and computers will carry on working at 85 volts AC whereas other stuff won't.

Comment: @Andyaka  That could very well be the situation -- just a low voltage occurrence that seems to be a complete outage -- and only affects devices that only operate at higher voltage.  I will look into that idea for my own understanding.  thx

Comment: What is the PSU wattage of the computers? They are required by ATX specs to stay on for some time at some load, perhaps at least one mains cycle at full rated load. So a computer sitting idle can be on longer.

Comment: @Justme It is a 650 Watt (here's the unit https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Power-Supply-Units/cxm-series-2015-config/p/CP-9020103-NA)
Interesting, I didn't know that was a requirement of PSU on computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its related to the (internal energy storage) power supply of the computer that remains functioning.

A load of 20 watts and energy storage of 200 watt-seconds would (at best) allow 10 seconds of operation.

If the power line voltage were 10% higher, just before the dropout, you'd get an extra 20% time.

Energy storage in a capacitor is

- energy = 0.5 * C * V^2

Thus 180 volts on the cap, and 500uF, stores 0.5 * 0.0005 * 180 * 180 == 8 watt seconds.

Comment: Very interesting.  And, I'm guessin that probably depends upon how much the system's internal components are draining the power supply too.  In other words if I have a huge graphics processor eating more power then the time available would be lower.  There is a 3rd tower computer that shuts off and it has a more intensive setup so probably makes sense.